# Should I specified the args in pom file to avoid Java heap space for CLOVER?

Tags: maven, clover

I have ran the mvn with clover to generate the clover report, but have found below:

```
ERROR: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError flushing coverage for recorder D:\workspace\nu\clover\clover.dbb6cs_he5gw8qr: Java heap space
Exception in thread "CloverFlushThread" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space.
```

Did there have any way to configure the `-Xms512M -Xmx1024M` for clover in maven(pom.xml)?
I have been finding it but there is no reason.  Please click [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CLOVER/CloverInstr). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are getting an OOO exception during test execution after Clover instrumentalized your code. If that is correct then you need to increase memory heap on the JUnit VM that is forked by Maven. You should add something like this on you POM file

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <version>2.18</version>
    <configuration>
        <argLine>-Xms512m -Xmx1024m</argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Good luck ;)